# Google custom search engine showing few results

Tags: search-engine, google-search, google-search-api

Here is my google search URL:

> https://www.google.com/search?q=site:flatrocktech.com+inurl:/careers&num=100&filter=0

and programmable search engine API endpoint:

> [https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key={api](https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=%7Bapi) key}&cx={engine id}&q=site:{website}+inurl:/careers&filter=0

First one produces 40+ results, while search engine API call gives me only 9 results. The only reason for creating custom search engine was that after some requests from Python requests library, Google is asking me to pass CAPTCHA verification. I know that custom search engines are different from global one. Do you know some workarounds to not land on that CAPTCHA verification page while sending requests from requests library?